# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher')

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

This is my first try at developing an Android App. I have the same error occurring twice (lines 5 and 13), but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

The Error: "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher'.

The problem is that I do have ic_launcher.png saved in Resources > drawable. Please help.

The Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="Solobuy.Solobuy">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
  <application android:label="Solobuy" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:name="mono.android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true">
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="Solobuy.Solobuy.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.Solobuy.Solobuy"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="Items" android:name="solobuy.ItemsActivity" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="Solobuy.Solobuy.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.Solobuy.Solobuy" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="Solobuy.Solobuy.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.Solobuy.Solobuy" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Try cleaning your project or restarting your ide?

Comment: Put your icon to `Project name-res-drawable` and clean your project.

Comment: Oh nvm. That didn't work :/. Same errors after debugging. I'm not sure what you mean to put my icon to Project name-res-drawable Lazy

Comment: Are you using a linux OS to developing? If yes, check if ic_launcher.png has read permissions.

Comment: Is ic_launcher set as an AndroidResource and not a BundledResource, check the properties of the file.

Comment: @Learnin2Code Were you able to solve this issue? If yes, could you post what you did to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change drawable into mipmap as you can see the list under "res" -- the ic_launcher exists in the document mipmap!

remember to press "Save" button and you will see the error out of your sight!